# Get url path of node using entity query

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the path of a node via entity query. So far I've managed to fetch the title of the node but I can seem to find a solution on how to get the node path/url. Here is a sample of my code

```
$facultyPostings = $query->get('node')
                           ->condition('status', 1, '=')
                           ->condition('type', 'careers')
                           ->condition('field_career_directory', 'Faculty Postings', '=')
                           ->sort('created')
                           ->execute();

foreach ($facultyPostings as $key => $faculty_postings_careers) {


     $careersNode = _nodeLoad($faculty_postings_careers);



    $variables['faculty_postings'][$key]['title'] = $careersNode->get('title')->value;
    $variables['faculty_postings'][$key]['path'] = $careersNode->get('path')->value;
}
```

Comment: are you using url aliases ?

Comment: @vishwa yes I am

Comment: If you are using D7 you can use drupal_get_path_alias(); If you have the node nid. In D8 you can use the service path.alias_manager

Comment: Currently using D8, I'm not yet very familiar with Drupal to be honest

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the service provided in Drupal 8 core.services.yml file. So in your loop you can use.

//think so this will get the nid

$nid = $careersNode->get('id')->value;

//This one is correct as per the documentation

$alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'.$nid);

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Path%21AliasManager.php/class/AliasManager/8.3.x

Comment: Hmm thanks for the insight, I believe which i'm currently using `$careersNode = _nodeLoad($faculty_postings_careers);` will load or get the node

Comment: Yes it will load the node.